# Whether frama-c can get the range of variables before a particular program code

Tags: c, frama-c

```
int main()
{
    int B = 1;
    int x = rand()%10+1;
    int x1 = rand()%10+1;
    int A = 1;
    while((B <= 5))
    {
            B++;
            A++;  
            if(B == x)
            {
                return 0;
            }
    }
    task(A) //The variable A passes in the range of values before the task function
    A = -2;
    return 0;
}
/*How can I use frama-c to get the range of A at task code if I want to get the range of A at task statement position instead of the range of A at the end of the program execution*/
```

How can I use frama-c to get the range of A at task code if I want to get the range of A at task statement position instead of the range of A at the end of the program execution

Comment: It seems unclear what you are asking "what is a frama-c"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you would like to know the interval of variation of `A` at a specific statement. I assume that you're are relying on the Eva plug-in, as it is the kind of information that is typically given by Eva (at least if I interpret well "instead of the range of A at the end of the program execution").

There are two possibilities. The first one is to use the programmatic API of Eva, namely the `Db.Value` module. This requires knowledge of OCaml and reading the [Frama-C developer manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-plugin-development-guide.pdf), but is the most flexible and stable way to access the information. Briefly speaking, `Db.Value.get_state` will, as its name suggests, return the abstract state computed after a run of the Eva analyzer, for the statement given as argument, while `Db.Value.eval_expr`, will, given an abstract state and an expression, compute the abstract value of the expression in the corresponding state.

The second possibility is to use the `Frama_C_show_each_*` family of built-in functions: whenever Eva encounters a function whose name starts with `Frama_C_show_each_`, it will print on the standard output the abstract value of the arguments given to the function in the current abstract state. Hence, adding `Frama_C_show_each_A(A);` before the call to `task(A)` will give you, with `frama-c -eva test.i`, among other things

`[eva] test.i:19: Frama_C_show_each_A: [1..2147483647]`

Note that I've modified your code in order to let it run properly with Frama-C:

- added prototype `extern int rand(void);` and `extern void task(int);`
- added a ';' after `task(A)`

Please ensure that you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example with your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this makes them much, much, easier to answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to try it

Comment: @liweizhang You're welcome. Don't hesitate to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it corresponds to what you expected.